# URL, code is not showing in GSC while Live URL testing

Tags: google-search-console

In Google search console when we do live test URL then the code of my blog https://pm-jan-yojana-india.blogspot.com/
not showing. Is it any issue on my blogger template or is it client side code issue? What steps should be taken to show the entire code in the GSC section?

I am looking to resolve indexing issue.